# Removing # from the url of an angularjs web application

Tags: angularjs, html

I am working on removing # from the url of an angularjs web application.
I have used the code : 
1.Inside the config block :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: true });
```

2.Inside head section of index.html

```
<base href="http://localhost:8383/angularjsapplication/app/">
```

I works fine and removes the # sign from the url. However when i refresh the page after the first load, it's showing error : No data received(In chrome)

please suggest any solution which can be done on client or serverside.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/116

Comment: Are you running it locally?

Comment: @Aravind : yes .for now i am running it locally. if it works fine then it will be deployed in server.

Answer (score 0):

In `href` attribut you don't have to write `http://localhost:8383`. It gives the following tag :

```
<base href="/angularjsapplication/app/">
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache you'll want to put this in your .htaccess-file to allow incoming deep links:

**RewriteEngine on**

```
  # Don't rewrite files or directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

**Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links**

```
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```